# Executing npm link from a common folder

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-link

I use custom built library and then link them between other libraries using '**npm link**'. One problem is that,

if I do '**npm install**' the links disappear and then I will have to go manually and do the linking.

In order to solve this issue, I am thinking of building a script to do npm link across libraries wherever needed but I am not sure if that will work because we will have to do npm link on the exact path from command line                instead of running from a common path from command line.

Example:

I have built a library called, @mycustomlib/ui-components and I use them in other projects.

In order for me to use it,  I would have to do the link in the appropriate project folder else I wouldnt be able to import.

Answer (score 1):

Any `npm link` you've set up will be overwritten when you `npm install`.

One option to avoid having to relink every time you `npm install` might be to create a new script in `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "install-local": "npm install && npm link @mycustomlib/ui-components"
}
```

Then just run `npm run install-local`.